# regex - get the distinct characters from a string from a list

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the distinct characters from a string which are in a list.

Currently, the pattern is `/^[!~]{0,2}/gm` which matches the first two characters however if the same character appears twice in the string, it'll take the repeating character instead of searching for another character that appears in the list. If `!!!~~~test` is passed, the match should be `!~`.

The code below seems to work however I'd prefer a 100% regex solution.

```php
$pattern = '/^[!~]{0,2}/';
$matches = [];
$operator = '=';
$value = $origValue;

preg_match($pattern, $origValue, $matches);
$matches = array_filter($matches);

if (count($matches) > 0) {
    $matchesValue = array_shift($matches);
    $matchArr = str_split($matchesValue);
    $matchArr = array_unique($matchArr);
    $matchesValue = implode('', $matchArr);

    ...
}
```

Update: please see https://regex101.com/r/6lMtfJ/2. I'm trying to select either an `!` or a `~` once at the beginning of a string. If the same character appears more than once, it should ignore the duplicate and move to the next character. More examples:

```
!test     -> !
!!test    -> !
!~test    -> !~
!~~test   -> !~
test!     -> no match
test~~~   -> no match
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _“however I'd prefer a 100% regex solution”_ - I’m not sure to what _problem_ exactly, and neither your description or the rudimentary “example” are really helping.

Comment: @04FS: please see the updated question with more examples - hopefully this helps explain my issue a little better.

Comment: As long as you are anchoring your pattern to be beginning of the subject (`^`), you can’t expect it to be “moving on” beyond the first two characters in any case. // What you want here is not a job for a singular regex on its own to begin with IMHO.

Comment: Apologies, @04FS, I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you saying what I'm trying to achieve is not a job for regular expressions? If so, what other way do you suggest? The way it is currently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `~!test` or `~~~test` or `!~!~!~test`?

Comment: @Toto: the first would return `~!`, the second would return `~` and lastly, the third would return `!~`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tests = [
'!test',
'!!test',
'!~test',
'!~~test',
'test!',
'test',
'~!test',
'~~~test',
'!~!~!~test',
];

$pattern = '/^(!~?|~!?)/';
foreach ($tests as $test) {
//~     echo "$test \t=> ";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $test, $m)) {
        $res = $m[0];
    } else {
        $res = "No match";
    }
    printf("%10s => %s\n", $test, $res);
}
```

**Output:**

```
     !test => !
    !!test => !
    !~test => !~
   !~~test => !~
     test! => No match
      test => No match
    ~!test => ~!
   ~~~test => ~
!~!~!~test => !~
```